# Is it possible to define a CustomUser and still use the standard admin screen?

Tags: django

A few different questions on the same topic:

I have defined a new CustomUser classes to the following, which is simply an extension of the default UserClass.

```
class customUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name='email address', max_length=255, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(null=True)
    Primary_address = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    Primary_address_zipcode = models.CharField(max_length=5, null=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Question 1: Is it possible to inherit attributes of the default UserClass (like first_name and last_name, last_login, first_created) without having to redefine in my new CustomUser class?

Question 2: Would it possible to use the existing User default page and just modifying it slightly to fit my CustomUser?  I ask because the default admin page has nice Group control, last_login and first_created field that I would like to use and I don't want to "reproduce" the same page. It would be nice has to add the extra fields I have defined in CustomUser to Person Info section of default admin page.

[image: Default Admin User page]

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You're going to want to use `AbstractUser` instead of `AbstractBaseUser`.

Details are provided here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-django-s-default-user

It creates a different table in the database (not `auth_user`), but still fully extends into the Django Admin quite elegantly.

Comment: I want to use email as the unique identifier instead of Username (in fact I want to disable username).  Can I do that by extending AbstractUser?

Comment: You probably should amend your question to say that then - otherwise, AbstractUser would be the proper solution.

Comment: So I can't extend user and disable username with AbstractUser?

Comment: That is correct, you need to use `AbstractBaseUser` if you want to change any of the default Django user fields of `username`, `password`, `email`, `first_name`, or `last_name` - or change which field is the username. The documentation is pretty clear on how this works: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.AbstractBaseUser

Comment: If using AbstractBaseUser, can I still leverage the admin User control page show above?